# Can you move your keeper with creepers using the teleport card?

Tags: fluxx

In Star Fluxx, can you move your keeper with creeper(s) attached to another player using Teleporter card?

Answer (score 3):

The Evil, Malfunction and Brain Parasites creepers say "Both cards stay together until discarded". This clearly means you can only move the keeper with the attached creeper.

Answer (score 1):

@zovits is correct - Creepers attached to Keepers generally stay that way, until a card explicitly says to do otherwise. That said, there is, in Star Fluxx, the special case of "Beam Us Up" which is specifically addressed in the [FAQ included in the rules.](http://www.looneylabs.com/literature/star-fluxx-rules):

> Q: What happens to Creepers attached to Keepers during **Beam Us Up**?
>   A: The Creepers stay with their Keepers until they reach a player's hand, at which point that player must immediately put them back onto the table in front of them.